# Memory layout of union of different sized member?

Tags: c, unions

```
typedef union epoll_data
{
  void        *ptr;
  int          fd;
  __uint32_t   u32;
  __uint64_t   u64;
} epoll_data_t;
```

Here `int` and `__uint32_t` are 4 bytes,while the others are 8 bytes.

When we set `fd` to an `int`,does it lie on the first 4 bytes or the last 4 bytes,or does it depend on endianness?

Some reason is appreciated.

Comment: In practice shorter types will always be at the beginning, but I'm not sure if or where this is spelled out...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It lies on the first 4 bytes. From the C99 standard §6.7.2.1/14 (§6.7.2.1/16 in C11 and C18):

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

This implies that the address of all members of a union is the same.

Comment: Not true, they can start at different locations due to padding. See Figure 3.5 in the ELF standard linked below. It is an example of how order of declaration of fields within a union/structure definition matters.

Comment: @user209051: Wrong. Assuming you meant Figure 3-6 (3-5 is a struct), notice that the bitfields are depicted with low addresses on the right and high addresses on the left.  The padding occurs after the members (with higher addresses).

Answer (score -2):

This really depends on ELF-ABI for that platform. See examples and figures give under section 3.1 in http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf It shows that it need not start at low address, if there is padding due to alignment constraints.

Comment: Wrong.  See my comment on my answer.  The ELF ABI is not authoritative/normative for the C language.