# Why can union be used this way?

Tags: c, unions

Isn't it true that members in union are exclusive, you can't refer to the other if you already refer to one of them?

```
union Ptrlist
{
    Ptrlist *next;
    State *s;
};

void
patch(Ptrlist *l, State *s)
{
    Ptrlist *next;

    for(; l; l=next){
        next = l->next;
        l->s = s;
    }
}
```

But the above is referring to both `next` and `s` at the same time, anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 5):

A union only defines that

```
&l->next == &l->s
```

that's all. There is no language-restriction of first accesses.

Comment: the &-operator has lower-priority than the ->-operator, so here the & returns the address of ->next and ->s respectively.

Comment: @lexer: If both are the same size, say 4 bytes, they will essentially point to the same memory.

Comment: @lexer: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352199/memory-layout-of-union-of-different-sized-member) question, the C99 standard is referenced saying that a pointer to the union is (under a conversion) a pointer to every one of the unions members.

Comment: @lexer: in this particular example yes: &l->next == &l->s == &l. but usually unions are used with struct-fields and in __packed__-format and then the fun starts.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, *all* members of a union are active at *all* times. The only thing to consider is whether the members are each in a valid state.

If you ever do want some level of exclusivity, you would instead require a tagged union. The basic idea is to wrap the union in a struct, and the struct has a member identifying which element in the union should be used. Take this example:

```
enum Tag {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
};

struct {
    Tag tag;
    union {
        int First;
        double Second;
    };
} taggedUnion;
```

Now `taggedUnion` could be used like:

```
if(taggedUnion.tag == FIRST)
    // use taggedUnion.First;
else
    // use taggedUnion.Second
```

Comment: Even though this is neat trick that could help you keep your pseduo-polymorphic code correct if you check the Tag value when appropriate; it should be pointed out that this guarantees no level of exclusion at all really.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing an assignment to `next` from `l->next`. Then, you "overwrite" `l->s` through the assignment `l->s = s`.

When you assign to `l->s`, it overwrites the memory held in `l->next`. If `next` and `s` are the same "size", then both likely could be "active" at the same time.

Comment: ok obviously I screwed the pooch on a C Standard I obviously missed, so downvoter, please explain

Comment: not the downvoter (wouldn't downvote your answer) but 'activate' should be replaced with 'overwrite', that's more correct

Comment: @Kevin: Ok, no problem. I always thought of it as activating.

Comment: you probably know that a 'common' use of a union is to mask one type to another, something like `union x {char cx[4]; long lx;}` so that you can see the bytes of a long via assignation.  there's no activation involved as both are 'active' all the time.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, in that case you are correct. But that is only because 4 byte = same length at long (4 bytes) - correct?

Comment: yes, but I do the same for others `union x {char cx[8]; int ix; long lx; double dx;};` NOTE: this is machine dependent but very common.

Comment: @Kevin: How does that work if `int` is 4 bytes, `long` is 4 bytes? Are you just masking the int and long and not the double?

Comment: @CodeMonkey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2276/discussion-between-kevindtimm-and-code-monkey)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's supposed to be like that. Both *s and *next point to the same memory location. And you can use both at the same time.. they are not exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true. You can use any member of a union at any time, although the results if you read a member that wasn't the one most recently *written* to are a little bit complicated. But that isn't even happening in your code sample and there's absolutely nothing wrong with it. For each item in the list its `next` member is read and then its `s` member is written, overwriting its `next`.

Comment: a little bit complicated = undefined behaviour ? I know this is strictly UB in C++, but I don't know about C.

Comment: @Alexandre: How is it UB? He stores l->next into local next and then overwrites l->next with l->s, since only one member of a Union can be "active" at a time.

Comment: @Code Monkey: OP's code is perfectly defined. I'm asking about the answer's sentence "the results if you read a member that wasn't the one most recently written to are a little bit complicated"

Comment: @Alexandre: In that case, yes - the sentence is confusing. I was particularly referring to "I know this is strictly UB" in your comment. I don't understand what you were saying.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Quoting hobbs' answer: "the results if you read a member that wasn't the one most recently written to are a little bit complicated". In C++, reading another member than the last one written is plain UB, not "a little bit more complicated". I'd like to know if C has the same wording.

Comment: @Alexandre: I guess I don't understand. I thought unions were the same in C++ as they were in C

Answer (score 0):

See http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/unions.html for an introductory discussion on unions.

Basically, it's an easy way to do type casting in advance. So, instead of having

```
int query_my_data(void *data, int data_len) {
  switch(data_len) {
    case sizeof(my_data_t): return ((my_data_t *)data)->value;
    case sizeof(my_other_data_t): return ((my_other_data_t *)data)->other_val;
    default: return -1;
  }
```

You could simplify it by doing

```
typedef struct {
  int data_type;
  union {
    my_data_t my_data;
    my_other_data_t other_data;
  } union_data;
} my_union_data_t;

int query_my_data(my_union_data_t *data) {
  switch(data->data_type) {
    case TYPE_MY_DATA: return data->union_data.my_data.value;
    case TYPE_MY_OTHER_DATA: return data->union_data.other_data.other_val;
    default: return -1;
  }
```

Where my_data and other_data would have the same starting address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

An union is similar to a struct, but it only allocates memory for a variable. The size of the union will be equal to the size of the largest type stored in it. For example:

```
union A {
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned short s;
};

int sizeofA = sizeof(A); // = 2 bytes

union B {
    unsigned char c[4];
    unsigned short s[2];
    unsigned int i;
};

int sizeofB = sizeof(B); // = 4 bytes
```

In the second example, `s[0] == (c[1] << 8) & #ff00 | c[0];`. The variables c, s and i overlap.

```
B b;
// This assignment
b.s[0] = 0;
// is similar to:
b.c[0] = 0;
b.c[1] = 0;
```

An union is restricted to primitive types and pointers. In C++, you cannot store classes in a union. All other rules remain basically the same as for a structure, such as public access, stack allocation and such.

Thus, in your example you must use a struct instead of an union.